# Natural two parameter probability distribution for a one-sided interval

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, beta-function

On the reals, a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ could be considered somewhat natural *(loose terminology, but a lot of stuff in nature occurs normally distributed, it has some really nice mathematical properties, etc)*. A [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with parameters $\alpha$, $\beta$ seems to play a similar role for the closed interval $[0,1]$. A sufficiently narrow beta distribution far away from either end of the interval can look close to a normal distribution, which makes sense.

Is there any equivalently natural two-parameter distribution for the one-sided interval $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: How about $\Gamma$?

Comment: $\Gamma$ seems perfect, I hadn't heard about it before. Thanks!